# Rigid Body Cache Will Not Clear

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

There are many similar issues to this on stackexchange, but none of the solutions work. I absolutely cannot get rigid body to ignore my initial tests with a simple cube and collision system.

Find attached the blend file I am working with. Note that about 15-20 frames in the chain "moves". That is from when I had a few links in my chain and I was testing the hinge effect using rigid body constraints. No matter what I try I cannot get this collision to be removed or updated...and I have tried the usual including moving and escaping, as well as changing the rigid body settings.

This is obviously a pretty bad bug, but does anyone anywhere have something that might work to get blender to recalculate the physics?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbO1JpZCEfo) suggestion from Blender Secrets?

Comment: Yes. That was the first video I came to looking for a solution. It does not work. Try doing that with the blend file I provided.

Comment: Ok. I didn't know whether you'd seen that one or not. Incidentally I'm adding your file link into your question where every one will see it. If you just put it in a comment it's easy to miss.

Comment: I think you've found a bug.  I'd highly encourage you to post it on the bug tracker-- it may be related to other, hard-to-reproduce bugs that I've encountered that cost me a lot of time :)  In the meantime, if all you want to do is to get this chain working, it appears there's a simple solution: select all, ctrl c copy; open a new instance, ctrl v paste.  Pasted objects get assigned properly to rigid body world now (it seems), but cached behavior does not.  If you link a bug tracker issue, I'd be interested to follow.

Comment: John - when I uploaded the file, the website wanted a url for the question. Hence why it was posted in a comment.

Nathan, given there are videos about how to clear the cache, I'd have thought it was a known bug. But I'll report it anyway. Thanks for the tip about copy and pasting...I'll give that a go.